# svn checkout - An error occurred during decompression

Tags: 14.04, svn

The following error occurs when I checkout a large repository:

```
E120104: ra_serf: An error occurred during decompression
```

What is the problem and how can I avoid it?

I tried `cleanup` and `checkout` thereafter, but it stopped with:

```
E120104: ra_serf: An error occurred during decompression
```

I am on Ubuntu 14.04, svn, version 1.8.8 (`r1568071`).

Comment: Looks like either a broken server or a bad connection that is corrupting the data in transit.  You will need to ask the svn developers for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Editing `~/.subversion/servers`, and having this:

```
[global]
http-compression = no
```

Solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Set following key-value to SVN conf file. That should do the trick.

```
DeflateCompressionLevel 5
```

- 1 is the lowest value.
- 9 is the maximum value.

Comment: What file exactly? `~/.subversion/config`? And where exactly / what section?